# getting backslash before every special character while executing the mobile shell commands in java

Tags: java, appium

Getting backslah "\" before every specail character while executing the Mobile shell script in java

i am trying to run
ip addr show $(awk 'NR==3{print $1}' /proc/net/wireless | tr -d :) | awk '/ether/{print $2}'

to get the wifi address of the device via adb shell but when script get executed then backslash get added before "$" sign.

like this 
Running '/usr/bin/adb -P 5037 -s 711KPSL0621238 shell ip "addr show \$(awk 'NR==3{print \$1}' /proc/net/wireless | tr -d :) | awk '/ether/{print \$2}'"'

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a character preceded by a backslash ( \ ) is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the java compiler.

For example, if you want to put quotes within quotes you must use the escape sequence, \", on the interior quotes.

To print the sentence: 
**He said "Hello!" to me.**

you should write:

```
System.out.println("He said \"Hello!\" to me.");
```